# Callback in function does not appear to be executing in Require.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, requirejs

I have a module in RequireJS:

> define(['jquery', 'jsonLoader'], function($, jsonLoader){
>
> ```
> function buildMenu()
> {   
>     jsonLoader('system/models/build/menu.json', function(data){
>         var output='';
>         // ...
>         return output;
>     });
>
> }    
>
> return {
>     buildMenu : buildMenu
> }
>  })
> ```

After executing `buildMenu()` function, it returns "undefined" (Because callback defined in `jsonLoader()` does not exectuting). I'm calling to the function here:

> define(["jquery", "core", "template", "jsonLoader", "debugger"],
>   function($, core, template, jsonLoader) {
>
> ```
> var config,
>     debug; 
>
> $(function() {             
>     jsonLoader('system/config.json',function(data){
>         config = data;
>         init();
>     });
> });
>
> function init()
> {
>     debug = new $.fn.debug;        
>
>     if(config.application.debug == true)
>         debug.enabled = true
>
>     // Build menu
>     debug.log("Building Menu...");
>     console.log ( template.buildMenu() );
> }
>  });
> ```

And the jsonLoader looks that:

> define(["jquery"],function($){
>
> ```
>  return function(name, callback){
>            $.get(name, function(data){
>               callback(data);
>            });   
>   };
> ```
>
> });

Where's a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous callbacks ...

Comment: You'll need to pass a callback into your buildMenu function, then call it from the jsonLoader callback.  It's callbackception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define(['jquery', 'jsonLoader'], function($, jsonLoader){

    function buildMenu(callback)
    {   
        jsonLoader('system/models/build/menu.json', function(data){
            var output='';
            // ...
            callback(output);
        });

    }    

    return {
        buildMenu : buildMenu
    }
});
```

And where you call it

```
define(["jquery", "core", "template", "jsonLoader", "debugger"], function($, core, template, jsonLoader) {

    ...

    function init()
    {
        ...
        template.buildMenu(function(output) { console.log(output); } );
    }
});
```

---

### Introduction to Promises

Now, all of this callback stuff, if you nest it even further, could get out of hand. Using jQuery Deferred, it looks like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'jsonLoader'], function($, jsonLoader){

    function buildMenu()
    {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        jsonLoader('system/models/build/menu.json', function(data){
            var output='';
            // ...
            d.resolve(output);
        });
        return d.promise();
    }

    return {
        buildMenu : buildMenu
    }
});
```

---

```
define(["jquery", "core", "template", "jsonLoader", "debugger"], function($, core, template, jsonLoader) {

    var config,
        debug; 

    $(function() {             
        jsonLoader('system/config.json').success(function(data){
            config = data;
            init();
        });
    });

    function init()
    {
        debug = new $.fn.debug;        

        if(config.application.debug == true)
            debug.enabled = true

        // Build menu
        debug.log("Building Menu...");
        console.log ( template.buildMenu().success(function(output){console.log(output);}) );
    }
});
```

---

```
define(["jquery"],function($){

    return function(name){
        var d = $.Deferred();
        $.get(name, function(data){
            d.resolve(data);
        });
        return d.promise();
    };
});
```